# Summing two different elements using sum function in xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Hi am having an XML as shown
    `<root>
    <price>
    <abc>20<abc>
    <fact>true</fact>
    </price>
    <price>
    <abc>20<abc>
    <fact>NA</fact>
    </price>
    <price>
    <abc>20<abc>
    <fact>false</fact>
    </price>
    </root>`

I need to sum up abc value which is having fact as true and false.This true and false will occur only once.Can any one guide me.I know to use sum if its for all price `sum(///abc)` but introducing condition am not able to do write.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a *predicate*: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a predicate with `or`:

```
sum(/root/price[fact="true" or fact="false"]/abc)
```

This only selects `price` with fact containing `true` or `false`, then sums their `abc`'s.